# Can I access the parent/sibling of a key in an observable?

Tags: mobx

Given an `observable` like:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { observable } from "mobx";

const a = observable({
  firstName: {
    value: "a"
  },
  lastName: {
    value: "b",
    foo() {
      // can I access firstName from `this`?
      return this.value;
    }
  }
})
```

Something like `getParent(this).firstName.value`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't but that has nothing to do with mobx. This is just how Javascript works.
As you know `firstName` and `lastName` are completely separated objects, that happen to be contained in the same parent object. You can't go `up` in object references.

Comment: I understand for pure JS, yes, but mobx knows the full tree (b/c it's deeply observable) so it very likely could track metadata between levels in the tree. I.e. when it's walking and "observable"-izing each layer, it could/should know "btw this is your parent".